# R dplyr - check difftime on previous rows

Tags: r, dplyr

my dataframe looks like this:

```
   dataframe <- read.table(text="
     id    send             paid
     1     2013-01-25       NA
     2     2013-02-21       2013-02-23
     2     2013-02-21       2013-02-25
     2     2013-02-21       2013-02-28
     3     2013-03-01       2013-03-02
     3     2013-03-01       2013-03-03
     4     2013-06-23       2013-05-03
    ", header=TRUE)
```

What I'd like to do is to create new column result in `dplyr` for each `id` that will count rows above where difference between send for actual `id` and `paid` dates above this `id` is less than 120 days.

In other words, there is no row above for `id` 1 so result going to be 0, `result` for `id` 2 should be 0 since value above is `NA`. Result for `id` 3 will be 3 since difference between `2013-03-01` and (`2013-02-23`, `2013-02-25`, `2013-02-28`) is less than 120 days. Result for `id` 4 should be 4 since difference between `2013-06-23` is less than 120 days for dates (`2013-03-03`, `2013-03-02`, `2013-02-28`, `2013-02-25`).

```
   result <- read.table(text="
     id    send             paid           result
     1     2013-01-25       NA             0
     2     2013-02-21       2013-02-23     0
     2     2013-02-21       2013-02-25     0
     2     2013-02-21       2013-02-28     0
     3     2013-03-01       2013-03-02     3
     3     2013-03-01       2013-03-03     3
     4     2013-06-23       2013-05-03     4
    ", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One could do it like this using the dplyr package:

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe$paid <- as.Date(dataframe$paid)
dataframe$send <- as.Date(dataframe$send)
dataframe$id <- as.numeric(dataframe$id)
dataframe$paid-dataframe$send

count_fun<-function(myid){dataframe %>% filter(id<=myid) %>% mutate(diff=abs(paid-last(send))<120)%>% filter(id<myid) %>% summarise(sum(diff, na.rm = T)) %>% pull()}

dataframe$result <- sapply(dataframe$id, count_fun)


  id       send       paid result
1  1 2013-01-25       <NA>      0
2  2 2013-02-21 2013-02-23      0
3  2 2013-02-21 2013-02-25      0
4  2 2013-02-21 2013-02-28      0
5  3 2013-03-01 2013-03-02      3
6  3 2013-03-01 2013-03-03      3
7  4 2013-06-23 2013-05-03      4
```

Explanation: First step, define a function that counts the rows of index smaller than a given index where the difference is less than 120 days.
Second step, apply `sapply` to the id column using the function of step 1.